# YARD How to document block argument type?

Tags: ruby, yard

Is there a way to avoid creating temporary variables just to document block's argument YARD type?

The snippet below works but these temporary variables doesn't look good.

```ruby
foos.each_with_object(Set.new) do |foo, obj|
  # @type [Set]
  set = obj
  # now set/memo variable is semi-typed and LSP can do type-based autocompletion
end
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, these should be documented in `#each_with_object` using `@yieldparam` and  `@yieldreturn` from Yard

Comment: @FrederikSpang is correct. [See Here](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#yield) for the docs and basic examples of the `@yield`, `@yieldparam`, and `@yieldreturn` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@param` like so:

```ruby
# @param foo [Integer]
# @param set [Set]
foos.each_with_object(Set.new) do |foo, set|
  # foo & set are LSP/YARD typed in this block
end
```

[image: YARD Solargraph @param type]

I'm not sure if it is fully idiomatic YARD approach but it works in LSP/Solargraph.

Originally I found this example in the [Solargraph spec](https://github.com/castwide/solargraph/blob/master/spec/pin/parameter_spec.rb#L40).